# Java FileOutputStream Created file Not unlocking

Tags: java, file-io

Currently am facing a problem with  FileOutputStream in my code used  FileOutputStream for creating file in my disk .Once file created there is no way for opening , deleting or moving file from its location ,***getting error message already locked by other user***  When stopped web server it working properly .how can i solve this issue.

```
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            String uploadedFileLocation) {

            try {
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                        uploadedFileLocation));
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
                while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You're assigning `out` two different `FileOutputStream`s

Comment: why you are assigning out two times? what if an exception happens why you are not flushing closing both input and outstreams in finally.

Comment: @MadProgrammer how both "out" are different ? same object name .. but one is not flushing there is no error

Comment: @MidhunPottammal You create one instance of a `FileOutputStream`, never close it, then replace it with another instance of `FileOutputStream` and close it, this is leaving one stream open...

Comment: @MadProgrammer ohh .. i thought when replaced other will gc by Java .now i tried system.gc() then its working .

Comment: There's no guarantee that the object would be GC'd, especially while it's hold native resources open, and you should never rely on that

Comment: Why don't use use [`Files.copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)?

Comment: @fge its web file upload

Comment: Yes, and? Have a careful look at the javadoc of the `Files` class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating two instances of `FileOutputStream` and assigning both to `out`, but only closing one.

Remove the second `out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));`.

Also, you should consider using a try-with-resources block

```
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation))) {
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

or `finally` block to ensure that the streams are closed

```
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    String uploadedFileLocation) {

    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation))
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException exp) {            
            }
        }
    }

}
```

See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details